# how to fix this error " PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_query() " in cake bake console

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I've seen this error in many places but the exact case.
I got this error while running the cake bake console, exactly after choosing C " controller " then choosing the default database config

i'm on Ubuntu 10.10 through Virtualbox 
i'm using xampp - and installed the cakephp through the command apt-get install cakephp

here is the error

```
Use Database Config: (default/test) 
[default] > 
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_query() in /usr/share/php/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo/dbo_mysql.php on line 588

Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_query() in /usr/share/php/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo/dbo_mysql.php on line 588
```

Comment: The error you are quoting in the title is different from that in the body.

Comment: you are right .. i pasted the wrong code .. thanks

Comment: It looks like you don't have the mysql extension activated in PHP. There should be a (commented-out) line in `php.ini` that activates it

Comment: @Pekka: That's what I thought too but doesn't XAMPP enable MySQL by default?

Comment: @Bolt it should, yeah. But this looks pretty clear, there is no other possible explanation as far as I can see

Comment: well do you happen to know what that line would look like ??

Answer (score 4):

Your issue is more than likely that some Linux distros have different php.ini's for Apache PHP and and PHP-CLI, it appears that your PHP-CLI (which cake baker will use) doesn't have the mysql_* functions enabled.

To fix, you'll need to locate the php.ini for the PHP CLI and uncomment the line which includes the mysql_* lib. should be something like "extension=mysql.so". To find the location of php.ini, run `php -r 'phpinfo();'` on the command line and scroll to the top to see the location of php.ini.

Comment: @Dunhamzzz, Why not just do `php --ini` instead of `php -r 'phpinfo();'`?

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling did the trick for me:

```
sudo apt-get remove php5-common
sudo apt-get install --reinstall php5-mysql
sudo apt-get install --reinstall php5-cli
```

(note: mine was *not* a live or system-critical php install - I was just trying to get phpsh working with some mysql code. ymmv.)

Answer (score 0):

Another thing people usually miss out is to set the path of extension directory itself.

For example, look at the `ini` file at [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13201095/632951). He had already uncommented the line `extension=php_mysql.dll` but had not set the appropriate `extension_dir`.

You need this line to be uncommented or added in:

```
extension_dir = "ext"
```

where `ext` is the path to the extension directory.

Answer (score -1):

I used Ubuntu 10.04 and 11.04 and faced the same obstacle which has been annoying for quite a while, since I want to use bake for certain solutions.

To fix it you can open a terminal and type here:

```
php -i | grep 'Configuration File'
```

which yields something like this:

`Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/lib`

Well and surprisingly enough this is not the default path to keep you `php.ini` file, it is rather `/etc/php5/cli/`

Now you can simply copy your `php.ini` into `/usr/local/lib` or see how to fix the Configuration File Path.

I assume you have `php5-pgsql` (using postgres) or `php5-mysql` (using MySql) installed. Otherwise you might set your Configuration File Path in any way