# Call to undefined function mysql_query()

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I wasn't able to find this issue on this site. when I load my page, i get the following error

```
Call to undefined function mysql_query()
```

So my checked my `phpinfo()` file and I couldn't find the mysql extensions or any extensions at all.
So I went into my php ini file and uncommented the extensions

```
extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

I restarted my apache server and mysql and yet nothing changed and the extensions are not being recognized. I have mysql server running, i have apache running with php,but I am having a hard time getting extensions to load. so I checked my extension directory (the directory my `phpinfo()` specified and there is nothing there.) MacPorts installed everything except my extensions. what the heck ?? And is there anything else I am missing.

## php.ini

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Dynamic Extensions ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; If you wish to have an extension loaded automatically, use the following
; syntax:
;
;   extension=modulename.extension
;
; For example, on Windows:
;
;   extension=msql.dll
;
; ... or under UNIX:
;
;   extension=msql.so
;
; ... or with a path:
;
;   extension=/path/to/extension/msql.so
;
; If you only provide the name of the extension, PHP will look for it in its
; default extension directory.
;
; Windows Extensions
; Note that ODBC support is built in, so no dll is needed for it.
; Note that many DLL files are located in the extensions/ (PHP 4) ext/ (PHP 5)
; extension folders as well as the separate PECL DLL download (PHP 5).
; Be sure to appropriately set the extension_dir directive.
;
;extension=php_bz2.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
;extension=php_gd2.dll
;extension=php_gettext.dll
;extension=php_gmp.dll
;extension=php_intl.dll
;extension=php_imap.dll
;extension=php_interbase.dll
;extension=php_ldap.dll
;extension=php_mbstring.dll
;extension=php_exif.dll      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
;extension=php_oci8.dll      ; Use with Oracle 10gR2 Instant Client
;extension=php_oci8_11g.dll  ; Use with Oracle 11gR2 Instant Client
;extension=php_openssl.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_pspell.dll
;extension=php_shmop.dll

; The MIBS data available in the PHP distribution must be installed. 
; See http://www.php.net/manual/en/snmp.installation.php 
;extension=php_snmp.dll

extension=php_soap.dll
extension=php_sockets.dll
extension=php_sqlite.dll
extension=php_sqlite3.dll
;extension=php_sybase_ct.dll
;extension=php_tidy.dll
;extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
;extension=php_xsl.dll
;extension=php_zip.dll

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Module Settings ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
;date.timezone =

; http://php.net/date.default-latitude
;date.default_latitude = 31.7667

; http://php.net/date.default-longitude
;date.default_longitude = 35.2333

; http://php.net/date.sunrise-zenith
;date.sunrise_zenith = 90.583333

; http://php.net/date.sunset-zenith
;date.sunset_zenith = 90.583333

[filter]
; http://php.net/filter.default
;filter.default = unsafe_raw

; http://php.net/filter.default-flags
;filter.default_flags =

[iconv]
;iconv.input_encoding = ISO-8859-1
;iconv.internal_encoding = ISO-8859-1
;iconv.output_encoding = ISO-8859-1

[intl]
;intl.default_locale =
; This directive allows you to produce PHP errors when some error
; happens within intl functions. The value is the level of the error produced.
; Default is 0, which does not produce any errors.
;intl.error_level = E_WARNING

[sqlite]
; http://php.net/sqlite.assoc-case
;sqlite.assoc_case = 0

[sqlite3]
;sqlite3.extension_dir =

[Pcre]
;PCRE library backtracking limit.
; http://php.net/pcre.backtrack-limit
;pcre.backtrack_limit=100000

;PCRE library recursion limit.
;Please note that if you set this value to a high number you may consume all
;the available process stack and eventually crash PHP (due to reaching the
;stack size limit imposed by the Operating System).
; http://php.net/pcre.recursion-limit
;pcre.recursion_limit=100000

[Pdo]
; Whether to pool ODBC connections. Can be one of "strict", "relaxed" or "off"
; http://php.net/pdo-odbc.connection-pooling
;pdo_odbc.connection_pooling=strict

;pdo_odbc.db2_instance_name

[Pdo_mysql]
; If mysqlnd is used: Number of cache slots for the internal result set cache
; http://php.net/pdo_mysql.cache_size
pdo_mysql.cache_size = 2000

; Default socket name for local MySQL connects.  If empty, uses the built-in
; MySQL defaults.
; http://php.net/pdo_mysql.default-socket
pdo_mysql.default_socket=

[Phar]
; http://php.net/phar.readonly
;phar.readonly = On

; http://php.net/phar.require-hash
;phar.require_hash = On

;phar.cache_list =

[Syslog]
; Whether or not to define the various syslog variables (e.g. $LOG_PID,
; $LOG_CRON, etc.).  Turning it off is a good idea performance-wise.  In
; runtime, you can define these variables by calling define_syslog_variables().
; http://php.net/define-syslog-variables
define_syslog_variables  = Off

[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = me@example.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
;sendmail_path =

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail(), even in safe mode.
;mail.force_extra_parameters =

; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the filename
mail.add_x_header = On

; The path to a log file that will log all mail() calls. Log entries include
; the full path of the script, line number, To address and headers.
;mail.log =

[SQL]
; http://php.net/sql.safe-mode
sql.safe_mode = Off

[ODBC]
; http://php.net/odbc.default-db
;odbc.default_db    =  Not yet implemented

; http://php.net/odbc.default-user
;odbc.default_user  =  Not yet implemented

; http://php.net/odbc.default-pw
;odbc.default_pw    =  Not yet implemented

; Controls the ODBC cursor model.
; Default: SQL_CURSOR_STATIC (default).
;odbc.default_cursortype

; Allow or prevent persistent links.
; http://php.net/odbc.allow-persistent
odbc.allow_persistent = On

; Check that a connection is still valid before reuse.
; http://php.net/odbc.check-persistent
odbc.check_persistent = On

; Maximum number of persistent links.  -1 means no limit.
; http://php.net/odbc.max-persistent
odbc.max_persistent = -1

; Maximum number of links (persistent + non-persistent).  -1 means no limit.
; http://php.net/odbc.max-links
odbc.max_links = -1

; Handling of LONG fields.  Returns number of bytes to variables.  0 means
; passthru.
; http://php.net/odbc.defaultlrl
odbc.defaultlrl = 4096

; Handling of binary data.  0 means passthru, 1 return as is, 2 convert to char.
; See the documentation on odbc_binmode and odbc_longreadlen for an explanation
; of odbc.defaultlrl and odbc.defaultbinmode
; http://php.net/odbc.defaultbinmode
odbc.defaultbinmode = 1

;birdstep.max_links = -1



[MySQL]
; Allow accessing, from PHP's perspective, local files with LOAD DATA statements
; http://php.net/mysql.allow_local_infile
mysql.allow_local_infile = On

; Allow or prevent persistent links.
; http://php.net/mysql.allow-persistent
mysql.allow_persistent = On

; If mysqlnd is used: Number of cache slots for the internal result set cache
; http://php.net/mysql.cache_size
mysql.cache_size = 2000

; Maximum number of persistent links.  -1 means no limit.
; http://php.net/mysql.max-persistent
mysql.max_persistent = -1

; Maximum number of links (persistent + non-persistent).  -1 means no limit.
; http://php.net/mysql.max-links
mysql.max_links = -1

; Default port number for mysql_connect().  If unset, mysql_connect() will use
; the $MYSQL_TCP_PORT or the mysql-tcp entry in /etc/services or the
; compile-time value defined MYSQL_PORT (in that order).  Win32 will only look
; at MYSQL_PORT.
; http://php.net/mysql.default-port
mysql.default_port =

; Default socket name for local MySQL connects.  If empty, uses the built-in
; MySQL defaults.
; http://php.net/mysql.default-socket
mysql.default_socket =

; Default host for mysql_connect() (doesn't apply in safe mode).
; http://php.net/mysql.default-host
mysql.default_host =

; Default user for mysql_connect() (doesn't apply in safe mode).
; http://php.net/mysql.default-user
mysql.default_user =

; Default password for mysql_connect() (doesn't apply in safe mode).
; Note that this is generally a *bad* idea to store passwords in this file.
; *Any* user with PHP access can run 'echo get_cfg_var("mysql.default_password")
; and reveal this password!  And of course, any users with read access to this
; file will be able to reveal the password as well.
; http://php.net/mysql.default-password
mysql.default_password =

; Maximum time (in seconds) for connect timeout. -1 means no limit
; http://php.net/mysql.connect-timeout
mysql.connect_timeout = 60

; Trace mode. When trace_mode is active (=On), warnings for table/index scans and
; SQL-Errors will be displayed.
; http://php.net/mysql.trace-mode
mysql.trace_mode = Off

[MySQLi]

; Maximum number of persistent links.  -1 means no limit.
; http://php.net/mysqli.max-persistent
mysqli.max_persistent = -1

; Allow accessing, from PHP's perspective, local files with LOAD DATA statements
; http://php.net/mysqli.allow_local_infile
;mysqli.allow_local_infile = On

; Allow or prevent persistent links.
; http://php.net/mysqli.allow-persistent
mysqli.allow_persistent = On

; Maximum number of links.  -1 means no limit.
; http://php.net/mysqli.max-links
mysqli.max_links = -1

; If mysqlnd is used: Number of cache slots for the internal result set cache
; http://php.net/mysqli.cache_size
mysqli.cache_size = 2000

; Default port number for mysqli_connect().  If unset, mysqli_connect() will use
; the $MYSQL_TCP_PORT or the mysql-tcp entry in /etc/services or the
; compile-time value defined MYSQL_PORT (in that order).  Win32 will only look
; at MYSQL_PORT.
; http://php.net/mysqli.default-port
mysqli.default_port = 3306

; Default socket name for local MySQL connects.  If empty, uses the built-in
; MySQL defaults.
; http://php.net/mysqli.default-socket
mysqli.default_socket =

; Default host for mysql_connect() (doesn't apply in safe mode).
; http://php.net/mysqli.default-host
mysqli.default_host =

; Default user for mysql_connect() (doesn't apply in safe mode).
; http://php.net/mysqli.default-user
mysqli.default_user =

; Default password for mysqli_connect() (doesn't apply in safe mode).
; Note that this is generally a *bad* idea to store passwords in this file.
; *Any* user with PHP access can run 'echo get_cfg_var("mysqli.default_pw")
; and reveal this password!  And of course, any users with read access to this
; file will be able to reveal the password as well.
; http://php.net/mysqli.default-pw
mysqli.default_pw =

; Allow or prevent reconnect
mysqli.reconnect = Off

[mysqlnd]
; Enable / Disable collection of general statistics by mysqlnd which can be
; used to tune and monitor MySQL operations.
; http://php.net/mysqlnd.collect_statistics
mysqlnd.collect_statistics = On

; Enable / Disable collection of memory usage statistics by mysqlnd which can be
; used to tune and monitor MySQL operations.
; http://php.net/mysqlnd.collect_memory_statistics
mysqlnd.collect_memory_statistics = On

; Size of a pre-allocated buffer used when sending commands to MySQL in bytes.
; http://php.net/mysqlnd.net_cmd_buffer_size
;mysqlnd.net_cmd_buffer_size = 2048

; Size of a pre-allocated buffer used for reading data sent by the server in
; bytes.
; http://php.net/mysqlnd.net_read_buffer_size
;mysqlnd.net_read_buffer_size = 32768

[OCI8]

; Connection: Enables privileged connections using external
; credentials (OCI_SYSOPER, OCI_SYSDBA)
; http://php.net/oci8.privileged-connect
;oci8.privileged_connect = Off

; Connection: The maximum number of persistent OCI8 connections per
; process. Using -1 means no limit.
; http://php.net/oci8.max-persistent
;oci8.max_persistent = -1

; Connection: The maximum number of seconds a process is allowed to
; maintain an idle persistent connection. Using -1 means idle
; persistent connections will be maintained forever.
; http://php.net/oci8.persistent-timeout
;oci8.persistent_timeout = -1

; Connection: The number of seconds that must pass before issuing a
; ping during oci_pconnect() to check the connection validity. When
; set to 0, each oci_pconnect() will cause a ping. Using -1 disables
; pings completely.
; http://php.net/oci8.ping-interval
;oci8.ping_interval = 60

; Connection: Set this to a user chosen connection class to be used
; for all pooled server requests with Oracle 11g Database Resident
; Connection Pooling (DRCP).  To use DRCP, this value should be set to
; the same string for all web servers running the same application,
; the database pool must be configured, and the connection string must
; specify to use a pooled server.
;oci8.connection_class =

; High Availability: Using On lets PHP receive Fast Application
; Notification (FAN) events generated when a database node fails. The
; database must also be configured to post FAN events.
;oci8.events = Off

; Tuning: This option enables statement caching, and specifies how
; many statements to cache. Using 0 disables statement caching.
; http://php.net/oci8.statement-cache-size
;oci8.statement_cache_size = 20

; Tuning: Enables statement prefetching and sets the default number of
; rows that will be fetched automatically after statement execution.
; http://php.net/oci8.default-prefetch
;oci8.default_prefetch = 100

; Compatibility. Using On means oci_close() will not close
; oci_connect() and oci_new_connect() connections.
; http://php.net/oci8.old-oci-close-semantics
;oci8.old_oci_close_semantics = Off

[PostgreSQL]
; Allow or prevent persistent links.
; http://php.net/pgsql.allow-persistent
pgsql.allow_persistent = On

; Detect broken persistent links always with pg_pconnect().
; Auto reset feature requires a little overheads.
; http://php.net/pgsql.auto-reset-persistent
pgsql.auto_reset_persistent = Off

; Maximum number of persistent links.  -1 means no limit.
; http://php.net/pgsql.max-persistent
pgsql.max_persistent = -1

; Maximum number of links (persistent+non persistent).  -1 means no limit.
; http://php.net/pgsql.max-links
pgsql.max_links = -1

; Ignore PostgreSQL backends Notice message or not.
; Notice message logging require a little overheads.
; http://php.net/pgsql.ignore-notice
pgsql.ignore_notice = 0

; Log PostgreSQL backends Notice message or not.
; Unless pgsql.ignore_notice=0, module cannot log notice message.
; http://php.net/pgsql.log-notice
pgsql.log_notice = 0

[Sybase-CT]
; Allow or prevent persistent links.
; http://php.net/sybct.allow-persistent
sybct.allow_persistent = On

; Maximum number of persistent links.  -1 means no limit.
; http://php.net/sybct.max-persistent
sybct.max_persistent = -1

; Maximum number of links (persistent + non-persistent).  -1 means no limit.
; http://php.net/sybct.max-links
sybct.max_links = -1

; Minimum server message severity to display.
; http://php.net/sybct.min-server-severity
sybct.min_server_severity = 10

; Minimum client message severity to display.
; http://php.net/sybct.min-client-severity
sybct.min_client_severity = 10

; Set per-context timeout
; http://php.net/sybct.timeout
;sybct.timeout=

;sybct.packet_size

; The maximum time in seconds to wait for a connection attempt to succeed before returning failure.
; Default: one minute
;sybct.login_timeout=

; The name of the host you claim to be connecting from, for display by sp_who.
; Default: none
;sybct.hostname=

; Allows you to define how often deadlocks are to be retried. -1 means "forever".
; Default: 0
;sybct.deadlock_retry_count=

[bcmath]
; Number of decimal digits for all bcmath functions.
; http://php.net/bcmath.scale
bcmath.scale = 0
```

## EDIT

I am using a mac and checking my settings above. I do also have the php_mysql.dll files installed as well

```
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

This is my `phpinfo()` page

[image]

there is 3 occurrences of the word mysql on my page.

## edit

ok i have a screenshot that shows where the extension dir is but when i go there, I don't see any extensions. could macports installation be corrupted ??

[image]

Comment: This is also more of a serverfault question.

Comment: make sure that you are editing the proper php.ini file, there are some sample (or etc) configs.

Comment: Are you sure that you are looking at the correct php.ini?

Comment: It is a blessing in disguise. I hope every PHP installed gives this error.

Comment: try reinstalling mysql dlls files
http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.extensions.php

Comment: @RezaSh Why we assume that the user is on windows?

Comment: @itachi : you can assume that the user is on linux ! the main idea is re installation , and thats just a sample link.

Comment: @ive updated my information above. I am using a mac

Comment: @JanDvorak I also have php_mysql extension uncommented as well in my php.ini

Comment: @RezaSh I am pretty sure I am using the right php.ini file. is there anyway to double check that. wouldnt not work if it couldnt find the php.ini file ??

Comment: simply as a test edit some thing in your php.ini, restart the webserver, and see the results (e.g using phpinfo();).
for example you may turn of/off register globals or short open tags or etc, and check the result

Comment: @RezaSh I completely deleted the php.ini I am using and yet phpinfo() still runs so I guess its not using the right one. But I added a screenshot of the extension dir, but when i go there, its empty. could i have a bad macport installation ??

Comment: search your hdd, or take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750580/how-to-find-the-php-ini-file-used-by-the-command-line , hope to help

Comment: @numerical25, Since this is closed (for goodness knows what reason), I posted the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/31088549/632951

Answer (score 10):

`mysql_query()` is not part of PDO so the DLLs you're checking (which are PDO's dll for MySQL support) are not the one you should check. You want to check `php_mysql.dll` (.so on linux servers).

But PDO is definitely the right way to access MySQL. It is way much better than using mysql_query().

Read more over here, [on PHP's PDO page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: It's probably for the best that `mysql_query` isn't even defined.

Answer (score 4):

So start using `mysqli_()` and stop using `mysql_()`

Read the big red box on [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) page

Use [mysqli_()](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) Or [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score 1):

These extensions are loaded from the respective .ini files under /etc/php.d. Try using the full path to them, like for mysql in /etc/php.d/mysql.ini use:

extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysql.so