# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), in register system

Tags: php

I got problem in my php code that saying me : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), i tried to fixed a lot of time but none result.
Any way my code is :

```
 <?php
    include 'header.php';
    include 'config.php';
    include 'footer.php';
    ?>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['rgstdo'])){

$u_name = strip_tags($_POST['u_name']);
$u_pwd = md5($_POST['u_pwd']);
$u_email = strip_tags($_POST['u_email']);

if(!empty($u_name) or !empty($u_pwd) or !empty($u_email)){
    $u_name = strip_tags($_POST['u_name']);
    $u_pwd = md5($_POST['u_pwd']);
    $u_email = strip_tags($_POST['u_email']);

        }

if(empty($u_name) or empty($u_pwd) or empty($u_email)){
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>ERROR, All fields were filled</div>";
    }else{ 
        $dbadduser = mysql_query("INSERT INTO admins
         ('u_name','u_pwd','u_email') 
         VALUES
         ('$u_name','$u_pwd','$u_email')") or die (mysql_error());

        if(isset($dbadduser)){
            echo "<div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'>Done, now you can login</div>";
            include './/index.php'
            exit;()

        }
    }
}


?>
```

Error message : `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in C:\xampp\htdocs\kownload\path\admin-rgst.php on line 29`

Comment: there is some special character in the else part, exactly after the insertion query. just copy pasted your source is dreamweaver, and found it..

Comment: you mean the capital letters ?

Comment: just try my answered source below..

Comment: missed a semi colon before exit and after exit, just correct it then..

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include 'header.php';
include 'config.php';
include 'footer.php';

if(isset($_POST['rgstdo'])){
    $u_name = strip_tags($_POST['u_name']);
    $u_pwd = md5($_POST['u_pwd']);
    $u_email = strip_tags($_POST['u_email']);

    if(!empty($u_name) or !empty($u_pwd) or !empty($u_email)){
        $u_name = strip_tags($_POST['u_name']);
        $u_pwd = md5($_POST['u_pwd']);
        $u_email = strip_tags($_POST['u_email']);
    }
    if(empty($u_name) or empty($u_pwd) or empty($u_email)){
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>ERROR, All fields were filled</div>";
    }
    else {
        $dbadduser = mysql_query("INSERT INTO admins ('u_name','u_pwd','u_email') VALUES ('$u_name','$u_pwd','$u_email')") or die (mysql_error());
        if(isset($dbadduser)){
            echo "<div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'>Done, now you can login</div>";
            include './/index.php';
            exit();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

just taken out the special character in your code. and corrected the semicolon `';'` in `exit;()` to `exit();`

Comment: New error : Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_query() in C:\xampp\htdocs\kownload\path\admin-rgst.php:20 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\kownload\path\admin-rgst.php on line 20

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201095/call-to-undefined-function-mysql-query possibly reading this question would solve this new error..

Comment: By the way i use Mysqli

Comment: so any error again then!!

Answer (score 0):

I use **mysqli**
so it was an error by me that i added mysql_query() not mysqli_query()

```
<?php
include 'header.php';
include 'footer.php';

if(isset($_POST['rgstdo'])){
    $u_name = strip_tags($_POST['u_name']);
    $u_pwd = md5($_POST['u_pwd']);
    $u_email = strip_tags($_POST['u_email']);

    if(!empty($u_name) or !empty($u_pwd) or !empty($u_email)){
        $u_name = strip_tags($_POST['u_name']);
        $u_pwd = md5($_POST['u_pwd']);
        $u_email = strip_tags($_POST['u_email']);
    }
    if(empty($u_name) or empty($u_pwd) or empty($u_email)){
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>ERROR, All fields were filled</div>";
    }
    else {
        $dbadmins = **mysqli_query** ("INSERT INTO admins ('u_name','u_pwd','u_email') VALUES ('$u_name','$u_pwd','$u_email')") or die (**mysqli_error**());
        if(isset($dbadmin)){
            echo "<div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'>Done, now you can login</div>";
            include './/index.php';
            mysqli_close($con);
        }
    }
}
?>
```