# automaticall updating the records every day

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using this code

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT `time` from `table`");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
$timeDiff = time() - $row['time'];
if ($timeDiff >= 86400){
  //run code
}
```

but I am getting an error in the second line can someone please help me with this.

Comment: What is the problem you're facing?

Comment: ` table` : The space at beginning is intended??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$datetime = new DateTime("+1 days");
$date = $datetime->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$timeDiff = time() - $row['time'];

if($timeDiff >= '$date) {

 //Code Here

}
```

**Edit:**

You can update your code in `your_file.php` and run this:

```
0 0 1 * * php /var/www/vhosts/your_somain.com/httpdocs/scripts/your_file.php
```

This will run once a month, on the first day of the month at midnight (i.e. January 1st 12:00am, February 1st 12:00am etc.):

For further explanation:

Reference: [tutsplus.com](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800)

Hope it will help you.

Comment: what if i want to check it monthly how will i do that?

Comment: Simply you can add this line `$datetime = new DateTime("+1 month");`

Comment: actually i am making a salary management system and i want the salary to be updates every month will this piece of code work with that?

Comment: Yes, it will work but it is not a good approach. Use a CRON job to handle this. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron. Please up vote and accept the answer if it solves your purpose. Thanks!

Comment: but when ever the code will run the month will be updates automatically right?

Comment: but i want the salary to be updated on 1st of every month not when ever the code runs

Comment: When you set the date to `+1 month` and then you apply your condition so it will updated on 1st of every month.

Comment: but there is a problem when ever the page is loaded on the first of the month it will keep updating it so the salary will be updates for than once that why i used the code which i gave up cant that work with

Comment: That why I said to you that kindly use CRON job for this purpose. Wait I will give you a small example.

Comment: i have no idea about the corn can u explain me how to do that plzzz

Comment: how should i run the line u mentioned

Comment: i have on another question what if the system is off will it still run?and the salary will be updated?

Comment: You uploaded it on server ?

Answer (score 0):

**output error**

```
 $q = mysql_query("SELECT `time` from` table`");

    if (!$q) {
       $message = 'Invalid query:'.mysql_error(). "\n";
       die($message);
    }

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
        $timeDiff = time() - $row['time'];

        if ($timeDiff >= 86400){
           //run code
        }
    }
```

Comment: if i want the time difference of one month what should i do?

Comment: i tried this code but i m getting error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_query()

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_query()   You should to check php_mysql.dll

Comment: what should i check in that?

Comment: reference:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201095/call-to-undefined-function-mysql-query

Comment: Do you want scheduled script every day?

Comment: Try using linux crontab

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the second line. The problem is the first line. 
"SELECT `time` from`table`" - table is a reserved keyword in mysql.